# Campos de utilizador

Tags: c#

Estou a desenvolver um projecto que utiliza os motores do Primavera V9.

Para este projecto necessito que existam determinados campos de utilizador.

Sei criá-los através do Administrador, mas o que pretendo é que eles sejam criados, automaticamente, pelo meu sistema.

Assim sendo, a minha pergunta é:

É possível criar campos de utilizador através dos motores?

Obrigado.

Comment: Olá Pedro, bem vindo ao stackoverflow. Recomendo que removas a questão e a coloques no forum interno em em https://developers.primaverabss.com/forum/.

Para utilizar o stackoverflow recomendo a leitura https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help, ou https://developers.primaverabss.com/faqs/?faq_filter=216

Para o forum interno da PRIMAVERA https://developers.primaverabss.com/faqs/?faq_filter=217.

Comment: Para ajudar. Não não é possivel a criação de campos de utilizador pela API.

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio. Era o que eu suspeitava, mas queria ter a certeza, porque não sou muito apologista de inserts nas tabelas havendo uma API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Sérgio Sereno já respondeu à tua questão (não dá pela API). Mas podes fazê-lo por SQL, criando os campos (CDU_) e tabelas (TDU_) normalmente e depois tens de registar os campos CDU_ na tabela "StdCamposVar" e registar as tabelas TDU_ na tabela "StdTabelasVar".